# creating an array from a command line option (python::optparse)

Tags: python, arrays, command-line-arguments, optparse

There is a python script which reads a benchmark name from command line like this:

```
-b benchname1
```

The code for this perpose is:

```
import optparse
import Mybench
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
# Benchmark options
parser.add_option("-b", "--benchmark", default="", help="The benchmark to be loaded.")
if options.benchmark == 'benchname1':
  process = Mybench.b1
elif options.benchmark == 'benchname2':
  process = Mybench.b2
else:
  print "no such benchmark!"
```

what I want to do is to create a an array of benchmarks for this command line:

```
-b benchname1 benchname2
```

So the "process" should be an array that is:

```
process[0] = Mybench.b1
process[1] = Mybench.b2
```

Is there any suggestion for that?

Thanx

Answer (score 8):

If you have Python 2.7+, you can use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module instead of optparse.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process benchmarks.')
parser.add_argument("-b", "--benchmark", default=[], type=str, nargs='+',
                    help="The benchmark to be loaded.")

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.benchmark
```

Sample run of the script -

```
$ python sample.py -h
usage: sample.py [-h] [-b BENCHMARK [BENCHMARK ...]]

Process benchmarks.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -b BENCHMARK [BENCHMARK ...], --benchmark BENCHMARK [BENCHMARK ...]
                        The benchmark to be loaded.

$ python sample.py -b bench1 bench2 bench3
['bench1', 'bench2', 'bench3']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    self.opt_parser.add_argument('-s', '--skip',
        default=[],
        type=str,
        help='A name of a project or build group to skip. Can be repeated to skip multiple projects.',
        dest='skip',
        action='append')
```

Comment: than use it as 'my.py --skip a --skip b'

Comment: I used "--skip benchname1 --skip benchname2" but I get this error: "AttributeError: Values instance has no attribute 'benchmark'".   The line it points is "if options.benchmark == 'benchname1':"   Did you mean I replace '-b' with '-s'?

Answer (score 1):

You can accept a comma separated list for benchmark names like this

```
-b benchname1,benchname2
```

Then process the comma separated list in your code to generate the array -

```
bench_map = {'benchname1': Mybench.b1,
             'benchname2': Mybench.b2,
            }
process = []

# Create a list of benchmark names of the form ['benchname1', benchname2']
benchmarks = options.benchmark.split(',')

for bench_name in benchmarks:
    process.append(bench_map[bench_name])
```

Comment: should I remove my "if, elif, else" then?

Comment: ok, I found it. There is no need for "bench_map". I pass the options through ',' seperated list then split them as what you said. Finally I append them to process with  "process.append(bench_name)"  thanks :)