# python: AttributeError, 'module' object has no attribute 'something'

Tags: python, command-line, attributes

Previously I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671383/creating-an-array-from-a-command-line-option-pythonoptparse). That problem solved but there are error while developing the script.

Currently, an option is obtained from command line like:

```
... -b b1
```

the code processing that is:

```
import Mybench, optparse
parser.add_option("-b", "--benchmark", default="", help="The benchmark to be loaded.")  
if options.benchmark == 'b1':
   process = Mybench.b1
elif options.benchmark == 'b2':
   process = Mybench.b2
...
else:
   print "no such benchmark!"
```

Now I have changed so that more than one option is passed to "-b".

```
... -b b1,b2
```

The code for this is:

```
process = []
benchmarks = options.benchmark.split(',')
for bench_name in benchmarks:
   print bench_name
   process.append(Mybench.bench_name)
```

If you notice, in the first code the process gets value like this:

```
process = Mybench.b1
```

Now I write this:

```
process.append(Mybench.bench_name)
```

I expect that this command line:

```
... -b b1,b2
```

results in:

```
process[0] = Mybench.b1
process[1] = Mybench.b2
```

However I get this error:

```
process.append(Mybench.bench_name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bench_name'
```

Is there any solution to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bench_name` is a string, not an identifier, so you need to use `getattr()`:

```
process.append(getattr(Mybench, bench_name))
```

Answer (score 2):

For me there's a difference between :
 - process.b1
 - process.bench_name => process."b1"

getattr() may be the key of your wills.