# OptionParser() display choices when --help in Python

Tags: python, optparse, optionparser

I need to create an "interface" to my script such that (runs by crontab):

1. When --help, terminal will display a list of choices (well formatted, separate by \n)
2. allow multiple choices input (comma delimited)

e.g. (something like the following)

```
python feedAnimals.py --help 
...... Choices:
           dog
           cat
           fish

python feedAnimals.py --pets dog,cat,fish
```

Is there anyway to do this with `type="choices"`?
Or can I use `type="string"`? I tried to insert `\n` between choices under the "help" option, but these seems to be neglected at run time.

Must be python 2.4 compatible :(

Comment: you want to add option for your script? or wish to create interactive area? like : select your option: 1)foo 2)bar and then user will select one of them. ?

Comment: it'll need to run on cronjob... so can't be interactive :(

Comment: I didn't got you completely. you wanna get `argv` in your script in `python 2.4`? so you didn't test `sys.argv` ?

Comment: In the OptionParser code where I specify the details of --help, I need to add in new lines... will this be possible?

Comment: new line for content of help? you means something like it: "Choices:\n\tdog\n\tcat\n\tfish" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the documentation for argparse, should do what you need - and help (-h, --help) is built in by default

https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

Comment: Need to be 2.4 compatible :(

Comment: You can install it for versions prior to 2.7 - google it

Comment: @user3388884 No you don't... and even if you do, as noted by gkusner, you can install `argparse` as a third party module. See [the PyPI page.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse), in fact `argparse` can run from python2.3 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

This is example of how to change `usage` value. Try it:

```
from optparse import OptionParser 
string = "Choices:\n\tdog\n\tcat\n\tfish"
parser = OptionParser(usage=string)
(options,args) = parser.parse_args()
```

You can also change your `string` to this style:

```
string = """
    Choices:
        dog
        cat
        fish
"""
```

Then test it:

```
$python code.py --help
```

In will show you this something like this result:

```
Usage: 
    Choices:
        dog
        cat
        fish


Options:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Look this related questions, the first with a good "type='choice'" example, and the second with multiple values:

[Set a default choice for optionparser when the option is given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898153/set-a-default-choice-for-optionparser-when-the-option-is-given)

[Processing multiple values for one single option using getopt/optparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109436/processing-multiple-values-for-one-single-option-using-getopt-optparse)

You may use something like this or process the arguments "by hand":

```
from optparse import OptionParser

def get_args():
  usage = "Usage: %prog [options]"

  parser = OptionParser()

  parser.add_option("--pet",
    type = "choice",
    action = 'append',
    choices = ["dog", "cat", "fish"],
    default = [],
    dest = pets,
    help = "Available pets: [dog, cat, fish]"
  )

  (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

  print options, args
  return (options, args)

(opt, args) = get_args()
print opt.pets
```

Then, run:

```
python test.py --pet cat --pet dog --pet fish
```

Comment: The question is a little bit different. I've tried to comment, but I don't have enough reputation and now there is a link to that similar question. Thanks for the tips, next time I'll elaborate a better answer!

Comment: I've improved the answer, with sample code, adapted and shortened version from the other question.

Comment: Other related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671383/creating-an-array-from-a-command-line-option-pythonoptparse